# Magento 2.1.8 Language Pack Only English is selected

Tags: language, magento-2.1.8

I've created a **Chinese and Japanese** store views for my Magento store.

In storefont the options for Japanese and Chinese are displaying. However, when I **click on Chinese or Japanese**, only English option is getting selected.

May I know what am i doing wrong. I followed exactly as per Magento doco to create the store views. My main problem is why chinese/japanese options not getting selected when I click on them?